# periodic boundary conditions - finite differences

Tags: math, fortran, fortran90, numerical-methods, pde

Hi I have a code below that solves non linear coupled PDE's.  However I need to implement periodic boundary conditions.    The periodic boundary conditions are troubling me, what should I add into my code to enforce periodic boundary conditions?  Updated based on modular arithmetic suggestions below.

Note, t>=0 and  x is in the interval [0,1]. Here are the coupled equations, below that I provide my code

[image: equations]

where a, b > 0.

Those are the initial conditions, but now I need to impose periodic boundary conditions.  These can be mathematically written as u(0,t)=u(1,t) and du(0,t)/dx=du(1,t)/dx, the same holds for f(x,t). The du/dx I have for the boundary conditions are really meant to be  partial derivatives.

My code is below

```
program coupledPDE 

integer, parameter :: n = 10, A = 20 
real, parameter :: h = 0.1, k = 0.05 
real, dimension(0:n-1) :: u,v,w,f,g,d 
integer:: i,m 
real:: t, R, x,c1,c2,c3,aa,b 

R=(k/h)**2.
aa=2.0
b=1.0
c1=(2.+aa*k**2.-2.0*R)/(1+k/2.)
c2=R/(1.+k/2.)
c3=(1.0-k/2.)/(1.0+k/2.)
c4=b*k**2./(1+k/2.)


do i = 0,n-1 !loop over all space points except 0 and n
  x = real(i)*h    
  w(i) = z(x)  !u(x,0)
  d(i) = z(x)  !f(x,0)
end do


do i=0,n-1
  ip=mod(i+1,n)
  il=modulo(i-1,n)
  v(i) = (c1/(1.+c3))*w(i) + (c2/(1.+c3))*(w(ip)+w(il)) -(c4/(1.+c3))*w(i)*((w(i))**2.+(d(i))**2.)    !\partial_t u(x,0)=0
  g(i) = (c1/(1.+c3))*d(i) + (c2/(1.+c3))*(d(ip)+d(il)) -(c4/(1.+c3))*d(i)*((w(i))**2.+(d(i))**2.)    !\partial_t f(x,0)=0
end do

do m=1,A 

   do i=0,n-1
       ip=mod(i+1,n)
       il=modulo(i-1,n)
       u(i)=c1*v(i)+c2*(v(ip)+v(il))-c3*w(i)-c4*v(i)*((v(i))**2.+(g(i))**2.) 
       f(i)=c1*g(i)+c2*(g(ip)+g(il))-c3*d(i)-c4*g(i)*((v(i))**2.+(g(i))**2.) 
   end do 
     print*, "the values of u(x,t+k) for all m=",m
   print "(//3x,i5,//(3(3x,e22.14)))",m,u   

  do i=0,n-1
   w(i)=v(i)
   v(i)=u(i)
   d(i)=g(i)
   t=real(m)*k
   x=real(i)*k
  end do

end do


end program coupledPDE

function z(x)
real, intent(in) :: x
real :: pi
pi=4.0*atan(1.0)
z = sin(pi*x)
end function z
```

Thanks for reading,  if I should reformat my question in a more proper way please let me know.

Comment: Just copy the values from n to 0 and from 1 to n+1 in each time-step. That's all.

Comment: Surely it's cleaner to only declare everything on the mesh `0,h,2h,...,1-h` and then use some simple modulo arithmetic for the shifting of indices. The periodic boundaries are taken care of automatically. Even better would be the use of whole arrays and the `CSHIFT` function.

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks for the help, however I  do not get what you mean by that.  Where am I copying those values, and what values do you mean?  Would I add code into when I start my time loop, or? (I understand this is a really simple idea to implement, sorry for the confusion on my end). Thanks again!

Comment: @RussF Thanks for the response also.  How do I declare that on the mesh?  I am having a real problem grasping how to do this.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Just declare all your arrays as `v[0:n-1]` etc. In your loops calculate `ip=mod(i+1,n)` and replace references to `i+1` by `ip`. Similar for `i-1`. If you define your loops as `do i = 0,n-1` everything is handled naturally. If you really need the value at x=1 then just copy the value from x=0 after you `i` loop.

Comment: Oh, yeah, you have a bounds error in your first loop. It should be `do i=0,n` not `do i=0,n+1`

Comment: @RussF I fixed my Bounds error in the first loop now.  Thanks.   I changed the dimensions of all the arrays as you suggest. I just want to clarify with what you said, I used modular arithmetic for the two discretization loops for the i+1,i-1.   Also all of my do loops except the first one, have been changed to i=0 to n-1.  My question is as follows, how come we don't need modular arithmetic for the factors v(i), g(i), etc.  Thanks again!  Also, when I did this, in my write command, I notice now u-f is non zero.

Comment: Show what you've done. The code above won't compile due to errors. Also make sure you use the `modulo` function for `i-1` and not `mod`. You aren't updating `v`,`w`,`g` or `d` so nothing can evolve.

Comment: @RussF Thanks, fixed now. I have just updated my code in the post above to show you what I have done using mod, modulo and changing the do loops. I omitted the code part where I updated v,w,g,d initially; but now it is in the code above.  I do notice now  at each time step if i print the solution, the 2nd and 10th point is the same, so I can see the periodicity.   However, did I implement it correctly?  The results are different than when I used the ghost method as described below.  I prefer to use modular arithmetic since I like doing everything on the mesh as you suggested.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to boundary conditions in PDE discretization is to use ghost (halo) cells (gridpoints). It may be not the most clever one for periodic BC, but it can be used for all other boundary condition types.

So you declare your arrays as

```
real, dimension(-1:n) :: u,v,w,f,g,d
```

but you solve your PDE only in points 0..n-1 (point n is identical with point 0). You could also do from 1..n and declare arrays form 0..n+1.

Then you set

```
 u(-1) = u(n-1)
```

and

```
 u(n) = u(0)
```

and the same for all other arrays.

At each time-step you set this again for `u` and `f` or all other fields that are modified during the solution:

```
do m=1,A 
   u(-1) = u(n-1)
   u(n) = u(0)
   f(-1) = f(n-1)
   f(n) = f(0)

   do i=0,n-1 !Discretization equation for all times after the 1st step
       u(i)=...
       f(i)=...
   end do 
end do
```

All above assumed explicit temporal discretization and spatial discretization with finite differences and it assumed that `x(0) = 0` and `x(n) = 1` are your boundary points.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!  Before I can comment further I need to go through all of this and think about it, as well implement it.  I will be back later.

Comment: I drew out a picture of the grid and I see what you mean now why u(-1)=u(n-1) and u(n)=u(0), so I get why you changed the array dimensions.  That is very helpful!  For the two discretization loops, I implemented these conditions on all the variables u,f,v,g.  Lastly, when I print out my solution at each time step, now I see that indeed the 1st and 11th value are the same!  Thanks for the thorough explanation, please let me know if I have incorrectly done something.  I have one question, is this method still stable/recommended in higher spatial dimensions?  Thanks!

Comment: @Integrals I personally use this method in 3D CFD computations. The advantage is that your computational statements are simpler and the same everywhere. The disadvantage is that you have to copy the boundaries often and it gets a bit more involved for implicit methods. The other option with `modulo` is also possible. I find the ghost cells more general.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer, this is very helpful for me.

Comment: Hi, sorry to be asking you something else through here, if I should post it as a question please let me know. I was wondering if my generalization of your code above to two dimensional periodic boundary conditions was correct:
    u(0,:)=u(nx,:);
    u(-1,:)=u(nx-1,:);
    u(:,0)=u(:,ny);
    u(:,-1)=u(:,ny-1)
where nx,ny are just the total number of steps in x and y, I have a square grid so they are equal. Thanks for your help. ( I would impose this for all of the arrays and also add into each of two discretization loops) I can see why you said you have to copy the boundaries often..